# Webscrape specific passages with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, iteration

```
<div _ngcontent-c22="" class="abstract-text row">
    <!---->

    <!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="col-12">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div _ngcontent-c22="" class="u-mb-1">
            <strong _ngcontent-c22=""> Abstract:</strong>
            <div _ngcontent-c22="" xplmathjax="">Text Text Text</div>
```

I want to scrape the text.
This is my current code, but I can not proceed further. Any recommendations?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url_list=["https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7414512"]
for url in url_list:
    try:
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
            result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

            soup = bs(result.text, 'html.parser')

            table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"u-mb-1"})
    except:
        print("\nERROR")
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see on the page is embedded as Json string. You can use `re`/`json` modules to extract it.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7414512'
data = json.loads(re.search(r'global\.document\.metadata=(.*?);', requests.get(url).text).group(1))

# uncomment this to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['title'])
print()
print(data['abstract'])
```

Prints:

```
Supplier Involvement and Contract Design During New Product Development

Early supplier involvement (ESI) infuses upfront supplier resources and expertise to accelerate the research and development (R&D) timeline, and allow for risk sharing. Successful implementation of ESI in a new product development setting, however, remains elusive due to the intricacy of interfirm collaboration while dealing with unproven technology and market uncertainty. Extending from prior ESI studies on supplier selection, resource integration, and relationship management, we propose game theoretical contracting strategies to achieve manufacturer objectives, such as predictable design timelines, sufficient supplier commitment, and radical in-process innovations. Taking into account various project factors, such as revenue forecast, technical uncertainty, market competition, and team capability, we propose an incentive compatible mechanism based on real option analysis to suggest which project stage to best engage the supplier. The supplier, in turn, can follow our analysis to determine whether to participate, and if so, the appropriate level of resource commitment. The equilibrium analysis provides managerial insights into how to best balance the time-to-market mandate with the need for accruing significant innovations through supply chain partnerships.
```